# Watching for changes in web3.isConnected()

Tags: web3js

I am using Meteor & Web3 to talk to a Geth node, and would like to have an event fire in web3 when the Geth node goes down.

Web3 has the ability to add callbacks to [web3.eth.isSyncing](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethissyncing) to detect changes, but [web3.eth.isConnected](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3isconnected) does not.

How can I detect changes in web3.eth.isConnected without having to use continuous polling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`web3.net.listening`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3netlistening)

```
web3.net.listening
// or async
web3.net.getListening(callback(error, result){ ... })
```

This property is read only and says whether the node is actively listening for network connections or not.

Returns

Boolean - `true` if the client is actively listening for network connections, otherwise `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried adding `web3.net.getListening(callback(error, result){ console.log(error,result})` to my meteor app. It fires on initialisation, but not when I stop the Geth node. My console is flooded with `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` messages though.

Comment: @glider so i assume its polling. a workaround is to fire `web3.reset()` when we have a  `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED `

Comment: Yeah, [web3/syncing.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/web3/syncing.js) polls for changes. How would I detect an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` event within Meteor?

Comment: @glider did you managed to get it work?

Comment: Not yet, thanks for your input though. Haven't found a way of detecting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` events yet, any thoughts?

Comment: `Meteor.setInterval(functinon, interval)` is what I was looking for - it will call the function every interval milliseconds. Combine this with web3.isConnected() and you have a continuously updating status variable.

Comment: @glider thats a dirty solution. Lets do it for now. I shall update when i heave something better.

Comment: Anyone ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

For full disclosure, and whoever may stumble upon this question in the future, the following code was what I was looking for...

```
function status() {
    try {
        Session.set('connected',web3.isConnected())
    }
    catch (e) {
        Session.set('connected',false)
    }
}
//Call the status function every second
Meteor.setInterval(status, 1000);
```

Comment: Yep - looking at the network traffic between the client & server side, Meteor is constantly polling the server side, albeit with really small requests. So perhaps this is the proper way to do it.