# How do you connect to a node from the server side of a meteor app

Tags: meteor, connections, server-side

This is the command I am using to run the node (a private testnet)

```
geth --networkid 420 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

This is the code I am using to connect to the node on the server side of my app

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
```

If I try `web3.isConnected()` on the server side it returns false

I also tried `console.log(web3.net.listening)` as recommended by the comments but this gave the error:

```
TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function
```

I can connect fine on the client side and `web3.isConnected()` returns true

I am running the app locally on my computer

Comment: Check with this how to verify is you are connected https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/watching-for-changes-in-web3-isconnected